# Delphi - applying Delta to a TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

My application uses a `TClientDataSet` and a `TDataSource` set. No `DataBase` involved. The `TClientDataSet` is saved in `XML` format. I save the `TClientDataSet` using the `DataSet.SaveToFile` method, and doying so, the saved file retains the Delta changes. I can't  use the `DataSet.UpplyUpdates` method, because as stated before, there is no `DataBase`  hence  there is no `Provider` also.

`DataSet.SaveToFile ('SavedFile.XML')  // this retains Delta changes`

`DataSet.ApplyUpdates (0)  // can't use it (no Provider)`

My question is: how can I force to apply the Delta changes to the `TClientDataSet` before saving it to a file? If a save to a `binary` format, the Delta changes would be applied?.
Note: closing and subsequently open the `TClientDataSet` does not work either.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean with `If a save to a binary format, the Delta changes would be applied?` - ie do you want to know would saving to the binary format retain the changes too (as XML does) or have you found that binary format doesent save the delta and you are wondering why it works differently with regard to the XML format?

Comment: @ain. I didn't yet tried the binary format, but nevertheless, since is in "binary" format, I don't know if it's possible to browse the file to check if the Delta was applied, and if possible, neither know how to do this. The basic question is how to force the `TClientDataSet` to apply the Delta changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To erase the saved changes just call [`TCustomClientDataSet.MergeChangeLog`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.MergeChangeLog).

If you do not need the change log at all, set [`TCustomClientDataSet.LogChanges`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.LogChanges) to `False` (`True` is default value) just after open the dataset.

Comment: I appologize );. How can I forget about the `ChangeLog` property? Thanks!